# [Redux][Axios][React] Adding redux state inside of a axios / action file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I want to add/change a redux state when the data is received from the backend. This state controls a loading spinner.
The code below is what I thought that should work.

What am I missing?

**CouriersActions.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { toastOnError } from "../../utils/Utils";
import { GET_COURIERS, ADD_STATE_LOADING } from "./CouriersTypes";

export const addStateLoading = (state_loading) => ({
  type: ADD_STATE_LOADING,
  state_loading,
});

export const getCouriers = () => dispatch => {
  var tempx = {show: true};
  addStateLoading(tempx);
  axios
    .get("/api/v1/couriers/")
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_COURIERS,
        payload: response.data
      });
      var tempx = {show: false};
      addStateLoading(tempx);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      toastOnError(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: show me the line from where getCouriers is calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of solving this kind issue, create custom hook for all services and where ever you need it.

```
export const useCouriers = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const getCouriers = async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(addStateLoading({ show: true }));
      const response = await axios.get("/api/v1/couriers/");
      dispatch({
        type: GET_COURIERS,
        payload: response.data,
        // I think this should be response.data.data
      });
    } catch (error) {
      toastOnError(error);
    } finally {
      dispatch(addStateLoading({ show: false }));
    }
  };
  return { getCouriers };
};
```

Inside component

```
const { getCouriers } = useCouriers();
// call where you need
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work with the exact code. I got an error saying that I couldn't use it with class component. But, as your answer helped me, I accepted the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use redux, check redux-toolkit, it helps a lot the development with redux.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

@rahul-sharma answer helped me to find this answer. I just called addStateLoading inside of dispatch.

**CouriersActions.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { toastOnError } from "../../utils/Utils";
import { GET_COURIERS, ADD_STATE_LOADING } from "./CouriersTypes";

export const addStateLoading = (state_loading) => ({
  type: ADD_STATE_LOADING,
  state_loading,
});

export const getCouriers = () => dispatch => {
  var tempx = {show: true};
  addStateLoading(tempx);
  axios
    .get("/api/v1/couriers/")
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_COURIERS,
        payload: response.data
      });
      dispatch(addStateLoading({ show: false }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      toastOnError(error);
    });
};
```